# What is the exact use of & in shell scripting?

Tags: shell

I'm very new to shell scripting. I have a basic doubt of what is the use of `&` in shell scripting? That is doing something like this :

```
commands arg &
```

Waits to give more input. But what is its exact use? How should I use it in real world?

Comment: In a bash script the ampersand “&” is used to fork processes. More info here http://superuser.com/questions/152688/why-run-a-linux-shell-command-with

Comment: A simple google search for "ampersand bash" would give you the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have used it there, it runs `commands arg` in the background, disconnected from your keyboard, and the shell immediately asks you for its next command.

As for the real world, I use it when I have a command that will take some significant time to run but does not require any input from me and will put all of its output into a file, for example

```
# walk through the whole filesystem looking for a particular filename
find / -name 'obscure.filename' -print > /tmp/found-it &
```